# How can i get this function working in Gravity Forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gravity-forms-plugin

I am currently making a form where the user should be able to add and delete a specific section from the form, it should be working like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Unfxn/27/)

```
-
```

The form has fields which only have to be filled in once, there are 5 fields in the form which the user should be able to duplicate.

Is it possible to achieve this with the html markup Gravity Forms uses,
if possible, how is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to skin this cat.

1. [List field](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/list/).
2. [Gravity Forms Repeater Add-on](https://wordpress.org/plugins/repeater-add-on-for-gravity-forms/).
3. [Gravity Forms Nested Forms](https://gravitywiz.com/) (part of the Gravity Perks plugin suite).